# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8

Application  sends the letter by reading the parameters with jsf form. I do not understand why and how to fix it, because when you run from the development environment everything works fine.
When I place my application on the VPS server, I get the next error stack (although the application works on the local host, as needed):

```js
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.<init>(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:709)
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:919)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:619)
 at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:393)
 at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:726)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
 at org.spirtus.controllers.CustomMailSenderController.sendfromFixedMail(CustomMailSenderController.java:63)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:304)
 at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:535)
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
 at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
 at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There's most likely a difference in the dependencies that you're including in your classpath at runtime. Have you compared the two environments in that respect?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create and compile the project used version jdk_8u151 and JRE. At that time, as on the server the project was launched under the later jre. Using the same version jre solved the problem. Ty.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is caused due to not having Unlimited Strength Java Cryptography Extension installed in your JRE.

Try installing(Copying JAR's) inside your JRE lib/security folder. Get it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

Just Download and Extract the Content. You should get two files **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar**. Copy this to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security` folder.

If that resolves the issue, You should consider upgrading your Java 8 version. This issue has been addressed in Java 8u161 or later version.

Comment: Unfortunately, these steps do not resolve my problem. Installing updated versions of Java did not help. I use java  8u161, u162, 9.

Comment: same here, I've updated my security policy to unlimited and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood there was a collision between cached libraries and the libraries that was added. So I tried to clean cache and it worked out pretty well. In Android Studio you should try File -> Invalidate caches / Restart.

Comment: It is expected that you should provide a detailed answer covering what caused the error at the first place and the solution.

Comment: This answer is for Android development. Thanks for your answer. Save me tons of debugging hours.

Answer (score 0):

By my side i uninstalled the jdk version i had then installed a recent one and it worked like a charm. so please update your jre or jdk to a recent version and the problem will be solved.